# Short Story Identification with a dragon at a well and a princess raised as a boy

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Trying to find a short story I remember reading in elementary school, so it was written early 2000s the latest. It was part of an anthology, but I can't remember any of the other stories in it, though I believe they were all fairy tale style stories. The story starts with a lost prince making a deal with a dragon he runs into at a well, that in exchange for water he'll give the dragon his first born daughter, but years later tries to get out of it by pretending the princess is a prince and raising her as his son. This deception works until the princess takes off her helmet after a sword-fight due to the heat (which she was instructed not to do) and the dragon kidnaps her, but offers her a deal that if she can defeat an arrogant prince in three competitions (chess, sword fighting, and one of her choice which ends up being archery) then he'll let her go. At the end it's revealed that the dragon is actually the prince and he was cursed into the form of a dragon during the day until he could find someone who could beat him in three fair contests, but because he had previously declared that no *man* could beat him at anything, he'd inadvertently made that true, making the curse more difficult to break. The dragon/prince also had a pet owl. For some reason I remember the author being Jane Yolen, but I am having trouble finding it.